# printing creating the wrong size sheet

Tags: python

I created an image using pillow, the size of an A4 paper (2480, 3508), and this image is saved in a variable, so I use win32print to be able to print the image, only when I pass the width and height information , my image only fills half of the sheet.

My Code

```
def imprimir(imagens_a4):

    printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

    for i in imagens_a4:
        printer_dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
        printer_dc.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
        # Define as configurações de impressão
        printer_dc.StartDoc('Placas Print')
        printer_dc.StartPage()

        width = 2480
        height = 3508

        # Imprime a imagem na página
        dib = ImageWin.Dib(i)
        dib.draw(printer_dc.GetHandleOutput(), (0, 0, width, height))

        # Finaliza a impressão
        printer_dc.EndPage()
        printer_dc.EndDoc()
        printer_dc.DeleteDC()
```

and here is an image to demonstrate better

[page created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLsPq.png)